# To delete a word in a line in file without deleting a whole line

Tags: shell-script, sed

I want to delete a string "www.yahoo.com" only if the line starts with **assign where host.name in [** and ends with **]** and also if the string is followed by comma(,) 
I need to delete that comma as well

```
assign where host.name in [ "www.google.com","www.yahoo.com","www.facebook.com" ]
```

My output should look like

```
assign where host.name in [ "www.google.com", "www.facebook.com" ]
```

I don't know how to achieve this. 
Kindly give me some idea about this code.

Comment: Grep doesn't do this stuff. You need a stream editor (`sed`) or something no less powerfull eg. Perl.

Comment: Looks like you don't just want to delete the Yahoo string but you want to replace it with a space.. ?

Comment: Only you know the source input; how much of the string `assign where host.name in [` is sufficient to identify the line where Yahoo is to be removed?

Comment: is this a school assignment?

Comment: @roaima yes exactly the same i want to delete a word and replace it with a space

Comment: Please [update your question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/541927/edit). Hiding clarifications here in the comments doesn't help anyone.

Answer (score 4):

Problems like this are typically handled in sed, awk or Perl. 
The standard sed solution is

```
sed '/^assign where host.name in \[.*\]$/s/"www.yahoo.com",//'
```

Your wording is odd.
People normally don’t say

> I have a pet ca followed by t.

they say

> I have a pet cat.

Similarly, rather than

> a string `"www.yahoo.com"` … if the string is followed by comma (`,`)

you should just say

> a string `"www.yahoo.com",`

unless you mean something more complicated, like maybe

> a string `"www.yahoo.com"` … if the string is followed by comma (`,`),
>   optionally separated by a space

in which case you should say that.

The above command does what your question asks for:
it deletes the string `"www.yahoo.com",`. 
If you want to do what you *showed,* and what you said in a comment,
add a space:

```
sed '/^assign where host.name in \[.*\]$/s/"www.yahoo.com",/ /'
```

Comment: Perhaps what they meant was to delete the string *optionally* followed by a comma (i.e. to handle the case where `"www.yahoo.com"` is the last entry in the list)?

Comment: `[[:blank:]]*,?`

Comment: @cas: Well, sure, we can sit around all day guessing what pattern the OP *really* wants to match; for example, ```s/[[:space:]]*"www.yahoo.com"[[:space:]]*,\{0,1\}[[:space:]]*/ /'```. But remember that `?` and `+` aren’t defined in POSIX regular expressions.